# Search for numbers in link text with Jquery regex

Tags: jquery, regex

I am new to jQuery.
I have a link to my shopping cart. If the cart is empty, I want to hide the checkout button with jQuery.
Hide button in this case:

```
<a href="../cart/" title="My cart" class="top-link-cart">My cart</a>
```

Show button in this case:

```
<a href="../cart/" title="My cart (6)" class="top-link-cart">My cart (6)</a>
```

How can I do that using something like jQuery `contains('\[0-9]\')` to find a number in the link.
(I know how to hide the button once I have a match.)

Comment: You may at least open up your mouth a little, to the res-ponders of this post.. whether you had picked up any solutions available here or not..?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Rajaprabhu. The answer of Smistry helped me out.

Comment: Fine.. :) have a good day..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($('.top-link-cart').text().match(/[0-9]+/g)){
    $('.top-link-cart').hide();
}
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/e3ShT/

Comment: This is unbelievable: I have been struggling the whole day and you come up with the solution in 1 minute!!! Thanx a million!!